# Docker-compose deploys my app, but the init.sql script data is not loaded

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, initialization

I am working on Windows, Docker Desktop version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89 and docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b

My docker machine is hyper-v

I am trying to initialize the mysql database docker container for the deploy of my spring jpa app.

I have a docker-compose.yml file with two services: mysql-docker-container and spring-jpa-app. This file is in /resources/ folder inside project. 
The init.sql file is located there too.

I am locating the init.sql in the same folder as application.properties because I read that with this configuration:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.type=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

and excluding HikariCP:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

it would load all database and data in init.sql

But instead, I get Communications link failure but still starts the application.

Postman works and gives respones but without the data that i want to load, results empty.

That is why I included the healthcheck to check if mysql container is "healthy" but I am not sure that is what I need.

Also, I tried to enter the mysql container (when app started after docker-compose up --build) in another git bash as administrator but I cannot access to it because docker ps -a is empty

docker-compose-yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:

    mysql-docker-container:
        image: mysql
        networks:
           - mired
        container_name: mysql-docker-container
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user
        ports:
            - 2012:3306
        volumes:
            - c:/Users/User/Documents/project/src/main/resources/db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        tty: true
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'mysqladmin ping']
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 2s
            retries: 10

    spring-jpa-app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile     
        networks:
           - mired
        container_name: spring-jpa-app
        links:
            - mysql-docker-container:mysql-docker-container
        depends_on:
            - mysql-docker-container
        ports: 
            - 8087:8080
        tty: true

networks:
    mired:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ADD app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.18.67.41:3306/database?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.type=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
logging.file=log/log.log
logging.level.org.springframework=info
logging.level.orghibernate=info
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>app</name>
    <description>Application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-rc.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
spring-jpa-app            | 2019-08-05 10:23:44.920 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
spring-jpa-app            |
spring-jpa-app            | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
spring-jpa-app            |
spring-jpa-app            | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Comment: init need some time to finished, meanwhile the DB will be off untill the init process is finished, I suggest you to look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/